# Can a lamp cause a fire if exposed to steam?

Tags: water, lamp

I have this lamp (IP20) in my bathroom, and was wondering what the hazards are. 
http://www.nordlux.com/en-US/FIND_YOUR_PRODUCT/Produktvisning/Chamber_-_fitting_8w-27226101.aspx
Will it just stop working, or can it actually cause a fire?

Comment: The steam can condense on the electrodes and cause a short with all of the short consequences.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Thanks. But if a short circuit happens, doesn't it just blow the fuse? (sorry, I'm not an electrical engineer)

Comment: In the best case it will. But fuses are not ideal.

Comment: The IP20 rating does not cover the high-humidity environment of a bathroom. The 100% humidity with condensation may shorten the life of the device or otherwise cause damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, yes it will blow a fuse if moisture inside causes significant conductive path where it shouldn't be.  But long-term high-humidity conditions may cause more subtle problems like faster degradation which will shorten the useful life-span of the appliance.

If it is a proper, rated appliance for consumer domestic installation, starting a fire is probably not in the list of top 5 potential problems.